# Reason to go around the world

Tags: travel

May it be that following question would fit better in Writers section (and then, I would like to ask for migrating of question there), but I hope that it can answered here, too - because in this story, many parts of world should be described (and thus, many parts of world would be more or less exactly determined).

I recently got idea on another story from my world - journey around the world. Side plan for this story is that both travellers (man and woman, lovers) will see many parts of world, try to live lives of people they shall meet ... and so on. All journey should take ten years, that is surely very long time.

---

At this I have thought about following reasons:

- **Bet** - but with whom and of what? (bet would better fit to travelling around within some days)
- **Quest** - to do what and who should be author of such quest? (quest would not take so long time)
- **Kidnapped** - nobody would return from kidnapping so long time (or not?)
- **Holidays** - ten years of holidays?
- **Just learning path** - a bit recursive problem, what would initiate such journey

But what else may be reason for such journey? Please, write another possible reasons for so long journey - or at least hints for reasons written above.

---

**Edit: (as partial answer to comment by Alexander)**

**Origin of lovers** - The Meadows, country surrounded by massive of the Cloudy mountains

**General political situation** - *calm before the storm*; queen Iris rules the Fallen dragon empire (based on two kingdoms united by marriage) as enlightened/benevolent dictator (establishes modern-like schools and modern-like hospitals, brings modern way of healthcare represented by *Icefingers' school*), The East plains slowly recovers from civil war

Comment: Some people take what are called sabbaticals during which they go on a journey exploring other cultures. Others are professional travelers, and they go around exploring other cultures and then reporting back to a travel magazine or writing diaries that will later be published. Both are things people have done and do now.

Comment: How developed is your world? Is it like XVI, XIX or XXI century Earth?

Comment: They belong to an NGO, like Greenpeace.

Comment: If you are asking for reasons why a person (or character) would undertake such a journey, then I'm afraid that's liable to be closed (likely as primarily opinion-based) anywhere on the network; how would answers be judged? Given that Writers SE is about *how to write* not *what to write*, such a question would almost certainly be considered off topic there. Here, it seems like it is off topic as asking about actions (specifically, motivations) of individual characters.

Answer (score 1):

It is an established tradition among the travelling traders, that each young adult, upon reaching the age of independence, shall travel out from their family caravan, with only a few graduation gifts to serve as their initial stock.

Almost all trader children make it to the opposite continental coast before returning to the safety of clan and hearth.

The truly brave, barter their way round-trip across one ocean to feed their wealth on the higher trade values found in those foreign lands.

Only the bravest circumnavigate the globe, spanning three oceans and facing danger from both pirates and savages, to bring home great treasure from the farthest corners of the world.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a research mission as per the Beagle with Charles Darwin. Except this one has your two characters aboard, each with a specific role to play on board. Their roles might be  linguist, scientist, doctor, captain, Chaplin or paying passenger adventurer etc.

Answer (score 1):

The most common reasons for people to take long journeys:

- **Because it's there** (why else but for religious reasons would anyone bother to climb a mountain?)
- **Curiosity** — there are unknowns out there and it itches that you don't know what they are.
- **Profit** — New sources of crititcal resources make a ton-o-money.  New routes for trade can stiffle competition.
- **Conquest** — slaves and taxes are even more profitable than trade.
- **Indoctrination** — because [Crom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PChN2A_uL6o) demands new believers!
- **Freedom!**  The old regime is too draconian!
- **Escape!**  I'm a fugitive being chased!

*I make no claim that any of the previously used reasons to traipse around the world would be suitable for a couple.*

Comment: I am worried about that you repeated me in some of your reasons; only you wrote it in else words

Comment: I do not believe so.  Which do you think are the same?